# PHP loading page as if POST never got sent

Tags: php, apache

I'm currently running PHP 5.3.9, Apache 2.2.22, Mandriva 2010.2.

We used to be running on an old as PHP4 machine, i've since migrated our server to a new box, and everything is now working (unfortunately with a few legacy settings like register_globals!), except one page.

This one page sends a large POST request sometimes, and when it sends something over x (I'm not sure of the exact number), the PHP script behaves as if it never received any $_POST at all and gives me undefined errors. With a smaller POST it behaves like normal (yay).

Example of POST (grabbed using Opera Dragonfly):

```
grid[153][1]    256663
grid[153][2]    629969
grid[153][3]    Some Name
grid[153][4]    PSSERVICE
grid[153][5]    PS Service (PSSERVICE)
grid[153][6]    
grid[153][7]    
grid[153][8]    
grid[153][10]   
grid[153][12]   
grid[153][13]   1
grid[153][14]   PAYMENT PENDING
grid[154][0]    2012-03-04
grid[154][1]    256343
grid[154][2]    630133
grid[154][3]    Some Other
grid[154][4]    PSSERVICE
grid[154][5]    PS Service (PSSERVICE)
grid[154][6]    0
grid[154][7]    0
grid[154][8]    0
grid[154][10]   0
grid[154][12]   0
grid[154][13]   0
grid[154][14]   JOB
.... etc,etc,etc.....
total_tech_val  2481.1118181818
total_parts 414.99
total_traveltime    152.44
total_adjustment    0
total_net_val   2481.1118181818
```

I've tried increasing limits within the php.ini file, heres a few examlpes:

```
post_max_size = 32M
max_execution_time = 60
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 5000
memory_limit = 128M
```

What could be causing this odd behaviour?

NOTE: There is no error given in output (with E_ALL on, apart from the undefined errors), or inside the error log.

EDIT: 
When doing a "var_dump($_REQUEST);", i am getting the first part of the grid[][] but missing everything else. (gets up to element [76][13] or so). So it appears as if its reaching a limit and being cut off.

I am running the suhosin extension.

phpinfo is available at http://jsfiddle.net/QVEK3/

Comment: Mattisdada do you have a sample of the data thats not being handled correctly? Also, what does var_dump($_REQUEST) gives you on such cases?

Comment: When i did that i did receive some data, but there was a large amount missing. (all the stuff at the end, the more important stuff).

Comment: Are you using suhosin' patch? If so, verify if the suhosin.post.max_vars is set to an appropriate value.

Comment: I am running suhosin patch, it wasn't set in my php.ini, but im looking at http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html and adding a few of the .post. values, so far no dice though.

Comment: Try changing the suhosin.request.* entries too. If that still doesn't work, you could post the phpinfo() and/or your php.ini.

Comment: phpinfo is available at http://jsfiddle.net/QVEK3/

Comment: Acctually the last lot of .request. modifications seemed to have done the job. Thanks! If you want to post it as an answer ill confirm it for you.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the config. Are you sure the browser is sending all the data? Try using Chrome Developer's Console or Firebug and see if the entire request is actually being sent.

Comment: Like i said before "Actually the last lot of .request. modifications seemed to have done the job. Thanks! If you want to post it as an answer ill confirm it for you. "

Comment: Yep, I posted as an answer for the sake of completeness, and I hadn't seen the new comment when I posted the last one. Glad to help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your php.ini configuration file is not limiting the data being sent.

Keep a eye on these variables:

```
post_max_size = 32M
max_execution_time = 60
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 5000
memory_limit = 128M
suhosin.post.max_vars = 3000
suhosin.post.max_array_index_length = 400
suhosin.post.max_array_depth = 200
suhosin.request.max_array_depth = 200
suhosin.request.max_array_index_length = 400
suhosin.request.max_vars = 3000
```